# Why is there no actions for event objects?

Tags: event, publisher-action, action

I would like to add a Publisher Action to an Event object so that I could have this action in Salesforce1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add an action to an Event object to be available in Salesforce1:

1. add a Global Action
2. add this new action to the Global Publisher Layout